# Which text component to use?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making a simple chat application and I am trying to find out which text component is more appropriate to use.The component will need to support coloured text , provide line wrap and support scroll pane. Also it must allow the user to choose the font thats going to be used ( size , style etc ).

Which is the best option for this ? Thanks .

Comment: have a look at the differences on this page: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html From your description I think the JEditorPane is probably the best option. It supports colored text whereas the JTextArea doesn't

Comment: Google didn't bring this up.. thanks tho ill give it a read.

Comment: @Hunter, if that was an answer, I could +1 it.

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks :) I didn't make it an answer because I didn't really explain much, just linked to a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JTextArea can do all those things and you might look into the Document interface since this is a chat app. The Document will give you the ability to sync two components like JTextField and JTextArea. Document is not a text field of any kind, but is to be used with one. JTextField has a constructor method for Document "JTextField(Document doc)". To set the color of you text just call the setForeground(Color) method of JTextArea, also this method is inherited from its parent component JComponent.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example {

    JFrame frameA = new JFrame("Example");
    JTextArea textA = new JTextArea();

    public Example() {
        frameA.setSize(600, 300);
        frameA.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = frameA.getContentPane(); // Set the Color of textA.
        textA.setForeground(Color.red);
        content.add(textA);
        frameA.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example exam = new Example();
    }
}
```

Comment: `JTextArea` doesn't support colored text. Both `JTextPane` and `JEditorPane` do though.

Comment: import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example {
  JFrame frameA = new JFrame("Example");
  JTextArea textA = new JTextArea();
  public Example() {
    frameA.setSize(600, 300);
    frameA.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = frameA.getContentPane();
    // Set the Color of textA.
    textA.setForeground(new Color(255, 150, 150));
    content.add(textA);
    frameA.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example exam = new Example();
  }
}

Comment: Now if someone can help me correctly display this code I will fix it, lol.

Comment: just textA.setForeground() would do . Thanks for that

Comment: textA is a `JTextArea` which can have colored text, but it can only be one color. You can't have multiple colors going on inside the same text area. So if you want all of the colors to be the same, then I guess this is fine. But in a chat application I would assume that only certain words would be colored and others would be black and white. `JEditorPane` and `JTextPane` support multiple colors.

Comment: Ah thats quite important Hunter. Thanks for pointing that out.